# JTextArea - are 2 different highlight colors possible?

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent

I want to highlight the text in a `JTextComponent` with two different colors.

Is this possible with `JTextArea` (and if yes how?) - or do I need to use `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` (if latter: which one is to recommend if the only thing I really want to 'style' are different background colors)?

thanks in advance

Comment: yes is possible to `highlight the text in a JTextComponent with two different colors` but in very reduced form, you would needed to use `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` because by using those JTextComponents is highlign easier and more comfortable

Comment: how can I do this with a JTextArea?

Comment: ok ... I got it .... just use two different HighlightPainters ...

Comment: yes ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,